# LC circuit poor man theory

Tags: theory, passive-networks

Ok, let's suppose we want to explain the resonant frequency of an LC circuit.
By kirchoff laws is not so difficult ending to the equation:

[image]

By using the [Wolfram alpha engine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%20%2b%20k*y%20=%200) I end up with the following solution:

[image]

( I used k = 1/LC ) so I guess the result is correct, a part for the constant part that I can't explain *intuitively*. I suppose there should be some explanation that drop one of the constant to 0, but I really can't figure it out why. So the question:
**Is there a simple explanation on how to choose the correct constant values in the result?**

Comment: Isn't this a question of phase?

Comment: @pjc50 probably but how explayn that one of c1 or c2 must be zero? It should be that way because in the real life we just see one signal :)

Comment: @Felice - neither need be zero. The single signal you see is just the linear sum of the two signals you identified. These are 90 degrees apart in phase; by selecting coefficients C1,C2 you see other phases (if C1=C2 you see 45 degrees phase shift and sqrt(2) amplitude compared with setting C2=0)

Comment: reasons for downvote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to a differential equation involves arbitrary constants (\$c_1\$ and \$c_2\$
in this instance) whose value cannot be determined unless the initial conditions are
known.  It is *not* necessary that one of \$c_1\$ and \$c_2\$ be zero. *Both* could be
nonzero, and you will still observe a (single)
sinusoid of the same frequency. As @pjc50 cogently
observed, it is a question of phase (that is, the initial phase value). 
Note that if both \$a\$ and \$b\$ are nonzero, then the
sum \$a\cos(\omega t) + b\sin(\omega t)\$ is not the sum
of two sinusoids of different frequencies, but rather 
a *single* sinusoid of frequency \$\omega\$ rad/s 
of a different initial phase:

$$\begin{align*}
a\cos(\omega t) + b\sin(\omega t) 
&= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left[\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos(\omega t)
+ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(\omega t)\right]\\
&=  \left.\left.\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right[\sin(\theta) \cos(\omega t)
+ \cos(\theta)\sin(\omega t)\right]\\
&= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(\omega t + \theta)\\
&= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\omega t + (\theta - \pi/2))
\end{align*}$$
where \$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\$ and we have used
the identity \$\sin(x) = \cos(x-\pi/2)\$ in getting to that last line.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple explanation on how to choose the correct constant
>   values in the result?

Since this is a **2nd** order differential equation, there are **two** independent solutions and the general solution is simply a weighted superposition.

Dilip has already answered correctly that the initial conditions, the value of *i* and \$\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ when \$t=0\$, determine the weights.

\$i(0) = c_2 \sin(0) + c_1 \cos(0) = c_1 \rightarrow c_1 = i(0)\$

\$\dfrac{di}{dt}(0) = \sqrt{k}\ c_2 \cos(0) - \sqrt{k}\ c_1 \sin(0) = \sqrt{k}\ c_2 \rightarrow c_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ \dfrac{di}{dt}(0)\$